# RSBarcodes_Swift how to use?

Tags: swift, code-generation, scanning, rsbarcodes

Sorry for Google translator...

Hello!
I want to understand the use of the [Swift RSBarcodes library](https://github.com/yeahdongcn/RSBarcodes_Swift).

1. How to assign a variable scanned code.

I tried to do so:

```
var MyVar:String = ""


     self.barcodesHandler = { barcodes in
            for barcode in barcodes {
                MyVar = barcode.stringValue
            }
        }
```

But this has no effect :(

2. How to generate code?

I tried to do so:

```
RSUnifiedCodeGenerator.shared.generateCode("2166529V", machineReadableCodeObjectType: AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Code)
```

But this has no effect :( What should I do to see the generated image. I do not understand.

Maybe someone has a full description of the library or working example.
I would be very grateful.

Sorry for Google translator...